# C++ programming not compiling <iostream>

Tags: c++

I'm beginning to learn C++ programming, I'm using the visual studio editor.
This is the simple code I entered:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << "Hello, comply";
    return 0;
}
```

I only added the "#include iostream" because my textbook says that is needed to let the program output to screen. I tried to compile and run in my command prompt and its giving me some error:

```
**C:\Users\edika\Desktop>gcc comply.c -o comply.exe
comply.c:2:22: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
                    ^
compilation terminated.**
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: gcc compiles a `.c` file as C, not C++, by default.   Change the file extension to something that indicates C++,  such as cpp.   Also change the driver program from gcc to g++, so your command line is something like `g++ -c comply.cpp -o comply.exe`.     If doing both those things still fails, then the installation of your compiler/library is broken or incomplete.   The ways to fix a broken installation depend on how it is broken  (e.g.  did an admin do the installation, or did you?   What was actually installed?).

Comment: @Peter Recommending `-c` isn't a great idea on your command. Why would you **not** link, and then name the subsequent object file as an *.exe?

Comment: On a side note, C++ programs don't typically use `<stdio.h>` for I/O, only `<iostream>` and other stream headers (`<sstream>`, `<fstream>`, etc). But you can use `<stdio.h>` if you really need to, though you should prefer `<cstdio>` instead.

Comment: First try removing `#include <stdio.h>`, second as someone suggested name your files `.cpp` or `.C`. I am not familiar w VS but I think it should compile than.

Comment: @sweenish   Consider it a typo.   I rarely work on small projects that are built from a  single source file.   Normally when I use gcc/g++ I (use a make file or similar to) compile a set of source files to objects first (with `-c`) and later link to build an executable (rather than going from source to executable via one command).

Answer (score 9):

you're using a C compiler for C++. Additionally, your file extension should be *.cpp to indicate C++ code.

You're using gcc, you need g++.

Install G++, change your file name to comply.cpp, then run "g++ comply.cpp -o comply.exe"

Comment: This is also attempting to use gcc on MS-Windows. Trying to cram Linux/Unix originated software, like gcc, into a foreign operating system that wasn't designed to run Linux/Unix-originated code turns out to be a major, major time sink, more often than not. Even experienced developers will struggle with this, not to mention those who are new to C++. Most of the time it takes much less time to simply install Linux from scratch, and get a fully working, fully configured, modern C++ compiler. It took me just an hour and a half, last time. Now, I'd just buy a Lenovo laptop with preloaded Linux.

Comment: Or you know, mingw.